# How can I access cassandra.yaml in Docker?

Tags: cassandra, docker

I use `cassandra` image to create cassnadra container. I use volumes as follow:

```
- ./samt_tmp/cassandra_data/cassandra:/etc/cassandra/
```

I want create `cassandra.yaml` from docker in my pc but this path isn't exist.

```
sed: can't read /etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml: No such file or directory
```

while can copy from this directory.
why can't create volume from directory?
how can create `cassandra.yaml` volume ?

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 ways you can access the file:

1. Start an interactive shell session with `-it` flag.
2. Operate on the local directory.

If you'd like to access `/etc/cassandra` in the container, you can start an interactive shell with:

```
$ docker exec -it container_name bash
```

You can then edit the `cassandra.yaml` configuration inside the container.

The second option is to access the external directory which in your case is `samt_tmp/cassandra_data/cassandra`. You can work on this directory since it is accessible on the host (outside the container). Cheers!